# big endian swap macro "uswap" leads to unexpected error

Tags: c, macros

I'm facing following problem.

The macro

```
#define uswap_32(x) \
((((x) & 0xff000000) >> 24) | \
(((x) & 0x00ff0000) >>  8) | \
(((x) & 0x0000ff00) <<  8) | \
(((x) & 0x000000ff) << 24))
```

get's following number as argument x = 0x49074808

Why does my program break/resets here??

Thx

EDIT:

Description of my real application:

I have a bootloader sitting at flash start address 0x08000000U going till 0x08004000U.
After the bootloader there is a `uImage` header(taken from uboot) in flash, with size 0x40.
In my application, I just want to check, if there is actually a correct uImage header, because I have two `bootloader` versions. One can handle images of type uImage and the other one can't. In the last case, after the bootloader application there is no uImage header at all, there is application code!

In the application I just want to check the header crc:

```
#define UIMAGE_FLASH_ADDRESS     (0x08004000U)
image_header_t *header;
header = (image_header_t *) UIMAGE_FLASH_ADDRESS;
if (image_check_hcrc(header))
    /* do something...*/




static int image_check_hcrc(const image_header_t *hdr)
{
    uint32_t hcrc;
    uint32_t len = image_get_header_size();
    image_header_t header;

    /* Copy header so we can blank CRC field for re-calculation */
    memcpy(&header, (char *)hdr, image_get_header_size());
    header.ih_hcrc = 0;         // byte order independent
    hcrc = crc32(0, (unsigned char *)&header, len);

    return hcrc == image_get_hcrc(hdr);
}
```

The call for uswap_32() happens in the last line of above function:

```
#define uswap_32(x) \
((((x) & 0xff000000) >> 24) | \
(((x) & 0x00ff0000) >>  8) | \
(((x) & 0x0000ff00) <<  8) | \
(((x) & 0x000000ff) << 24))

# define cpu_to_be32(x)     uswap_32(x)
# define be32_to_cpu(x)     uswap_32(x)
#define uimage_to_cpu(x)        be32_to_cpu(x)
#define cpu_to_uimage(x)        cpu_to_be32(x)



#define image_get_hdr_l(f) \
    static inline uint32_t image_get_##f(const image_header_t *hdr) \
{ \
    return uimage_to_cpu(hdr->ih_##f); \
}
image_get_hdr_l(magic)      /* image_get_magic */
image_get_hdr_l(hcrc)       /* image_get_hcrc */
image_get_hdr_l(time)       /* image_get_time */
image_get_hdr_l(size)       /* image_get_size */
image_get_hdr_l(load)       /* image_get_load */
image_get_hdr_l(ep)     /* image_get_ep */
image_get_hdr_l(dcrc)       /* image_get_dcrc */

#define image_get_hdr_b(f) \
static inline uint8_t image_get_##f(const image_header_t *hdr) \
{ \
    return hdr->ih_##f; \
}
image_get_hdr_b(os)     /* image_get_os */
image_get_hdr_b(arch)       /* image_get_arch */
image_get_hdr_b(type)       /* image_get_type */
image_get_hdr_b(comp)       /* image_get_comp */
```

Comment: Can you say *how* it "breaks/resets"? What's the expected result? What's the actual result? And how do you use this macro (actual code)?

Comment: your macro looks goods. share how you call it

Comment: I test your macro in http://www.compileonline.com/compile_c_online.php and it works without problems:  `main()
{
   unsigned int A = 0x45231512;
   printf("%02X\n", uswap_32(A));
}`

Comment: Are you sure you pass an **unsigned** integer to your macro?

Comment: Where in your application is the `uswap_32` happening?

Comment: There is too much happening here, and you state that "after the bootloader application there is no uImage header at all, there is application code!". I can't directly relate that `uswap_32` failing. Can you make a concise test case that shows just `uswap_32` failing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a good idea to assign x to a local variable within a macro. Otherwise, if an expression is passed as an argument to the macro, it will be evaluated 4 times. For example, uswap(2+3), or even worse, uswap(some_func(x)).

Second issue - you need to add explicit UL type modifier for the constants. Here is a safer version of the macro:

```
#define uswap_32(x) ({\
    uint32_t _x = (x);\
    (uint32_t)(\
        ((_x & 0xff000000UL) >> 24) | \
        ((_x & 0x00ff0000UL) >>  8) | \
        ((_x & 0x0000ff00UL) <<  8) | \
        ((_x & 0x000000ffUL) << 24)); \
})
```